# How to edit the Getting Started/Info page of a new app

Tags: 2sxc

Just a simple question.
How do I edit the getting started/info page of an app that I've created using 2sxc?

TIA
cheers
MartyNZ

Comment: I've wanted to do this for years and always assumed I'd stumble upon in someday soon. Never did. Bookmarking this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're the first person to ask this in years :)

As of now it automatically gets it from the 2sxc catalog on 2sxc.org/apps

We chose this central location because it allows us to

1. Update it "remotely" to give instructions or also notices about upgrades
2. Include security notices if relevant

So the right way to do it is to publish your app on the catalog for everybody and edit the data there. If you would like to do that, please contact the 2sxc team ;)

Comment: Nice one :)
I will do exactly that as soon as I have something useful to share.